# Wordpress show subcategories of categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

Is it possible to show subcategories of categories in Wordpress?

Let's say I have category A and B. In A I have A1, A2 and A3. In B B1 and B2.
Now I would like to show the categories on the frontend... something like:

```
Category A:
- A1
- A2
- A3
Category B:
- B1
- B2
```

Is this possible in Wordpress in an easy way? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, in your theme set the depth argument passed to nav_menu function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 1):

A simple search for 'subcategories' on wordpress.org plugin area returns lots of examples.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=subcategories

Comment: Yep, but I came here to ask because of this... ;) I searched for it before but there are so many posts from 2 or 3 years ago when it was not possible, that I decided to ask here to get a trusted answer.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Makes sense I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

1) Showing Subcategories while you are on any category page:

```
<?php
if (is_category())
{
$cur_cat = get_query_var('cat');
    if ($cur_cat) 
    {
        $new_cats = wp_list_categories('echo=false&child_of=' . $cur_cat . '&depth=1&title_li=&&show_count=1&hide_empty=0');
        echo '<ul>' . $new_cats . '</ul>';
    }
}
?>
```

2) Show All top Categories:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('depth=1&title_li=&exclude=1&show_count=1&hide_empty=0'); ?>
```

3) show All top Categories + Subcategories like Tree menu:

```
Use FoCal plugin.
```

4) also, try this code :

```
http://wpworks.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/displaying-categories-and-subcategories-tree-on-wordpress/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Show Categories and subcategories in Drop Down List In Woocommerece in Wordpress**

```
   <option value=''>All</option>
```

get_results($sql);
    foreach ($allfilters as $singlefilter) {

```
    ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $singlefilter->slug;?>" "<?php if($singlefilter->slug == $singlefilter->name) echo 'selected'; ?>"> <?php echo $singlefilter->name;?></option>;

<?php }
```

?>